# Grails Strange issue with view not rendering

Tags: grails

I have a method in my controller redirecting to another method whose view is not rendering. The method being redirected to does have a view with the method's name but for some reason after hitting submit after logging in the next view doesn't render. I know that the method associated with the view is being called because other code in this method is executing, just its view isn't rendering. If I manually navigate to the view the URL it does render fine in the browser. Any ideas?

Comment: So what's the actual result of "the view is not rendering"? What do your controller actions look like?

Comment: I put in the username and password and hit the submit button and the browser stays on the same page. It doesn't go to the next page. I have some console logging statements in the method that is supposed to render the next view and those statements do get printed. If I manually type the URL of the next page it renders in the browser without any problem.

Comment: Please track down the problem until you have minimal code snippets and post them here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get around this might be using jQuery to read a JSON response and construct a redirect URL from that.